# Diode logic AND gates

Tags: digital-logic, diodes

I am new to electronic engineering (year 1 university student). I want to know: what if in this diode logic gate the 5V on the right-top corner changes into a number greater than 5.7V and then for VA and VB one is 0V while another is 5V? I have already watched some tutorials from YouTube and it said that when the input from right is 5V, it is impossible for VN to become 5.7V so VN could only be 0.7V when one of VA is 0V and another is 5V. So what will happen if I change the input from right (the 5V power supply) into a number greater than 5.7V?

[image: diode AND gate]

Comment: what is "the input from right"? I see two inputs, A and B, and one output, C. C is on the right, but it is an output, so I don't understand "the input from right". Do you mean the 5 V power supply?

Comment: Yes I mean the 5V power supply, sorry!! orz

Comment: you know the diodes will be around 0.7.. and the source voltage 5V or higher, the difference between the diode voltage and the source will all fall on that resistor, if you make it higher it will increase the current and more voltage on the resistor also, you could look at LED circuits which have a resistor in the same way often.

Answer (score 1):

Well... No. The maximum voltage at VN is 5V. Can't get more than the supply voltage. So if you want VN to be 5.7V, then the supply voltage must be 5.7V.

If either VA or VB is 0V then VN   will be 0.7V only if the supply voltage is greater than 0.7V.

If both VA and VB are high,(even higher than the supply voltage), then VN will equal the supply voltage.

If both VA and VB are high and the supply voltage is higher, then VN will equal the lower of VA or VB +0.7.

For example suppose VA = 4.0V, VB = 5.0V and the supply voltage is 6.0V, then VN = 4.7V.

Comment: Oh, sorry for my typo before(I have edited now). But if the supply is 5.7V, one of VA and VB is 0V, will the VN drop to 0.7V?

Comment: @EdwardHuang: That diode will be forward biased, VN at \$0+V_F\$. There will be almost 0.7 V more "over" *R*, the current through *R* will be somewhat higher, \$V_F\$ will be *insignificantly* higher.

Comment: @EdwardHuang: Yes VN will drop to 0.7V. See also my update.

Comment: @RusselH:Thanks a lot! But I do not know why...